Power BI Add if statement to VAR
How to add if statement in below VAR?
if statement will be like this:
if(AssetMaintenanceRequests[Month]) = "JAN" then VAR (as below)

VolumeJAN =

var Color = AssetMaintenanceRequests[Month]

var CarModel = CALCULATE(MAX('VOLUME-JAN'[volume]),AssetMaintenanceRequests[Month]= Color)

return CarModel

help me for this power bi
